# Access permissions to google folders docs etc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions, google-drive-api

I wrote a script in google sheets to convert a spreadsheet to a pdf and email it to me when someone clicks on a button..
The first time it is done a message pops up asking to allow this script.

It says this will allow access to folders, email doc and delete them etc.

Is there a way to only allow or deny the so-called app to certain folders?

thanks to those you have the answer

Comment: Is your concern that the other users will get access to your files? That's not the case. The script will always run as the user that executes it.

Comment: Because it says that allowing the script to run it will open up doors to third-party apps and there is information on people's drives. So I thought they are agreeing to allow access and I don't want to break Data Protection. I'm worried about all users files.